# knitr (R) - how not to embed images in the HTML file?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

This is probably very easy but I can't seem to find it in docs. I would like to not embed the generated images in the HTML file itself.

So basically I want knit2html() to produce a HTML file with seperate image files (which are then linked to / shown in the HTML). The basic behaviour is that the script embeds the images as a base64 string. The problem with this is that in IE, large images won't show up (i.e. appear to be missing). Any idea how I can seperate the images from the HTML output?

My example .Rmd file ('knit.Rmd'):

````
```{r}
plot(3)
```
````

And my .R file to generate the HTML from this:

```
library(knitr)

knit2html('knit.Rmd')
```

This example generates a HTML with the plot as an embedded base64 string.

Comment: Can you give us a short markdown example of what you are doing and list the R functions you are calling...

Comment: I've added a minimal example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at the `knit2html` help page, you will see that :

```
This is a convenience function to knit the input markdown source and
call ‘markdownToHTML()’ in the ‘markdown’ package to convert the
result to HTML.
```

Then you look at the `markdownToHTML` help page and read that there is the following argument :

```
 options: options that are passed to the renderer.  see
           ‘markdownHTMLOptions’.
```

So you look at the `markdownHTMLOptions` (still not lost ?) and see the following option :

```
 ‘'base64_images'’ Any local images linked with the ‘'<img>'’ tag
      to the output HTML will automatically be converted to base64
      and included along with output.
```

With the following command, you should see the default options on your system :

```
R> markdownHTMLOptions(default=TRUE)
[1] "use_xhtml"      "smartypants"    "base64_images"  "mathjax"       
[5] "highlight_code"
```

So may be you can try to knit your markdown file with :

```
knit2html("knit.Rmd", options=c("use_xhtml","smartypants","mathjax","highlight_code"))
```

Not tested, though...

Answer (score 19):

You can just add `self_contained: no` to the output options in the .Rmd header. For example:

```
---
title: "Data visualisation with ggplot"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
---
```

Answer (score 10):

Its not `knitr` that does this, `knitr` just produces a modified markdown file after running the `R` chunks. So you need to look at the help for the `markdown` package to figure out...

Its the `base64_images` option. Coffee hasn't kicked in yet, so I haven't exactly sussed out how to set/reset individual markdown options, but clearing them all out works for me:

```
 > knit2html("foo.Rmd",options="")
```

producing

```
 <p><img src="figure/unnamed-chunk-1.png" alt="plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-1"> </p>
```

in `foo.html`.

If clearing all those options breaks other stuff, then read up on `markdownHTMLOptions`.

Comment: First, R chunks in the .Rmd file are rendered into a modified knitr .md file. Then rendered into .html, e.g. `render('foo.Rmd')`. R interpreter displays the generic knitr filename. https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-knitr-markdown-html/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple way to have figures in a separate html file, which will reduce its size significantly.

Add this chunk in the beginning of the *.rmd file:

````
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
#suppress the warnings and other messages from showing in the knitted file.
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=8, fig.height=6, fig.path='Figs/',
                      echo=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```
````

Option 'fig.path' tells R to save pictures into 'Figs' folder. The rest of options is not required for the task.

Click this button:

[image: Click this button]

Make sure the check box is not checked:

[image: Make sure the check box is not checked]