# How to display pie chart in HTML page in R (Without save it as image)?

Tags: r, charts, pie-chart

I am new to R programming and i had one problem in R charts.
Is it possible to show the generated pie chart into HTML page without saving it as image in R programming?

Here is my code:

```
slices <- c(10, 12,4, 16, 8)
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")
pie(slices, labels = lbls, main="Pie Chart of Countries")
```

If any body know please give your suggestion.

Thank you...

Comment: Why the restriction of not saving the plot to file? Without this information it is hard to provide concrete advice.

Comment: I have no idea what the point of JulianUrbano's comments were, but the correct answer is that you can do this with markdown, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870589/knitr-r-how-not-to-embed-images-in-the-html-file

Comment: Package [`R2HTML`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2HTML/index.html) also have convenient wrappers to help you embed your graph in an html file.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the [`Shiny`](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) package. It can be used to implement analyses as interactive web applications. It took me just a few hours to install the software, and get something running. The [website of shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) shows good examples, and [contains a good tutorial](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/).