# Embed image in HTML r markdown document that can be shared

Tags: html, r, image, r-markdown

I have an R markdown document which is created using a shiny app, saved as a HTML. I have inserted a logo in the top right hand corner of the output, which has been done using the following code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $head = $('#header');
     $head.prepend('<img src=\"FILEPATH/logo.png\" style=\"float: right;padding-right:10px;height:125px;width:250px\"/>')
   });
</script>
```

However, when I save the HTML output and share the output, of course the user cannot see the logo since the code is trying to find a file path which will not exist on their computer.

So, my question is - is there a way to include the logo in the output without the use of file paths? Ideally I don't want to upload the image to the web, and change the source to a web address.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870589/knitr-r-how-not-to-embed-images-in-the-html-file

Answer (score 6):

You can encode an image file to a data URI with `knitr::image_uri`. If you want to add it in your document, you can add the html code produced by the following command in your header instead of your script:

```
htmltools::img(src = knitr::image_uri("FILEPATH/logo.png"), 
               alt = 'logo', 
               style = 'float: right;padding-right:10px;height:125px;width:250px')
```