# knitr: how to stop base64 image embedding in R vignette

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a simple test Rmd vignette in my R package:

````
---
title: "Vignette Test"
author: Snowy Seal
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Vignette Test}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.extra='', fig.pos='H', collapse=TRUE, comment=NA)
``` x

A simple plot:

```{r simpleplot, fig.width=7, fig.height=6, fig.align='center'}
plot(1:10)
``` x
````

(Sorry, the spurious 'x' chars are to let me embed the extra backtick blocks!)

Normally the resources of the generated HTML file (css/images) are embedded to make single html file. Images are embedded using data uri mechanism which uses base64 encoding in the image. For a large number of plots this makes the HTML file huge and my final package too big for CRAN.

According to an answer to a previous question about this [stackoverflow/questions/14870589](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870589) the way to stop base64 data uri image embedding in HTML output files is to specify the option `self_contained: no` in the YAML header of your Rmd file (next to the `toc: true` option).

This does indeed have an effect - the `img` tags now have `src="path/to/image.png"` links, BUT the installed R package does not contain these external resource files.

The R package build and install with vignette processing is complex and I can't understand what I need to do to get these external resources installed into the R package doc/ directory.

Comment: Yes, I agree - working around this is not great. After much fiddling I've discovered that the generated png images (which are then base64 encoded) on Centos 8 are 6 times larger than those generated under Windows 10 ! The windows png images are indexed images according to GIMP. How to make knitr under Linux generate such images opens up yet another can of worms...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.  This is somewhat error-prone, and might not help enough with the size of your package:  base64 expands things, but only by about 33%, so I'd think about other ways to reduce your size instead.

The idea is to process your vignette in the vignettes directory before building your package.  If your vignette is called `test.Rmd` and you have in your YAML header

```
output:
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    self_contained: false
```

then you'll find processing it by `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` creates a directory called `test_files`, which will contain your plots.  To get this into your final package, create another file in the `vignettes` directory called `.install_extras`, and put the line

```
test_files
```

in it.  (This is a regexp pattern which will match the path of any file in that directory.  If it catches too much, make it more specific.)

I don't advise doing this, however.  It is quite error prone, because if you just click on "knit" in RStudio, the plots in the `test_files` directory won't be updated.  It will be really easy to edit the vignette and forget to update the plots.  You're better off finding some other way to reduce the size of your package, or publishing it somewhere else besides CRAN.